# Matching a regular expression for an attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a value coming in an API , lets say `status`. The status can have 4 possible values - `Initial Dev Status Ok`, `Initial Dev Status Failed`, `Initial QA Status Ok` and `Initial QA Status Failed`.

I want to get all the records that have trailing `Status Ok` - both Dev and QA. I want to use regular expression to achieve the same.

I tried various combinations but I am not getting the correct result. For eg - I tried with `/([^Status Ok])$/` and `/([^non client]*)$/` but both of them are not correct and I am not getting the correct results.

What would be the regex pattern for the same. Apologies if this question has already been asked.

Comment: You only need `/Status Ok$/`

Comment: `[^…]` doesn’t mean what you think it means.